# Undefine a keyword in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net, spotify

I am currently working on an c# application that uses the spotify api. For the parsing of the Newtonsoft stuff I am using Newtonsoft.Json. But when receiving a track, the json includes a key `explicit`, and explicit is a keyword. So my question is, if there is a way to give the track class a member called explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the @ prefix to escape reserved keywords.

```
var @explicit = ...
```